# Listing all papers which cite my references

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I would like generate a list of all papers which cite my references, sorted by most recent. In other words I want all papers which are "2 publications away" from mine, which cite the references in my papers, but which are not references of my references. This would provide an easy way to see what new research is closely related to mine, even if they do not cite my papers.  Has anyone thought of doing this?  How could it be done?

Comment: What search options are on the sites that contain the papers? This sounds like a coding / scraping task which will be off topic here. Why not do a search on scraping websites and then adapt what you find.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using Google Scholar: Suppose your paper is *[Alternative to mental hospital treatment: I. Conceptual model, treatment program, and clinical evaluation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12910826986926402159)*. The *[cited by](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12910826986926402159&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en)* link lists the papers citing your paper (and can be [sorted by date](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&cites=12910826986926402159&scipsc=&q=&scisbd=1)). Now you just need to click the cited by link for each of the papers identified in the previous step and merge the resulting lists.

Comment: I do not see how to merge the lists?  What I want is a sort of automatically generated list (I do not want to click each paper that I have ever referenced individually)

Comment: It does appear that some coders could probably compile the data from Google Scholar though.  I just don't know who to ask for that.

Comment: @DouglasSirk You'd have to merge lists manually. This method is surprisingly fast. I just tried it for a paper with seven citations, it took maybe thirty seconds to open all "papers which are '2 publications away'," and it wouldn't take much longer to merge, you could always automate the merging.

Comment: For the merging, you could use automated websites for sorting lines alphabetically, and for removing duplicate lines. Like https://miniwebtool.com/sort-lines-alphabetically/ and https://miniwebtool.com/remove-duplicate-lines/

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to code, the path to the solution is:
You need the DOIs of your cited references and create a script which regularly checks their newest citations via [CrossRef's API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc).